# Update only ONE table in database

Tags: php, mysql

Whenever I execute an update-query, my whole table is updated. What do I have to do when I just want ONE value to be updated?

Here is my database structure:

```
ID   ||     photo     ||   sequence
1    ||   test.png    ||      1
2    ||   bla.png     ||      2
```

Whenever I execute this script,

```
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    $project = new Project();

    $project->sequence  = $_POST['sequence'][$key];
    $projectid          = $_POST['photoid'];

    if($project->updateProject($_DB, $projectid)) {
        $feedback = "OK";
    } else {
        $feedback = "NOT OK";
    }
}
```

Results in this:

```
ID   ||     photo     ||   sequence
1    ||               ||      4
2    ||               ||      2
```

So, what do I have to do to just update the `sequence`-value in the database without touching the rest of the data in the database...

**FUNCTION**:

```
public function updateProject($db, $id) {
        $sql = "UPDATE tblProject SET 
            sequence = '".$db->escape($this->sequence)."'
        WHERE id = '".$id."'";
        return $db->insert($sql);
    }
```

**INSERT FUNCTION**:

```
  public function insert($sql) {
    mysql_query($sql, $this->_connection);
    return mysql_affected_rows($this->_connection);
  }
```

Comment: OK - i have a suggestion. Enable general log and see the queries. Probably another query is run in another part of the script. When you see query, you'll probably be able to track it back to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a problem with your `$project->updateProject()` function.

Try with simple query:

```
$qry = "UPDATE tblProject SET sequence = '".$project->sequence."' 
        WHERE ID =".(int)$projectid.";
mysql_query($qry);
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, whenever you get this problem, you are updating your table without any WHERE clause. Like the code below:

```
UPDATE myTable SET myField = 'newValue';
```

In this case, all of your stored records will update with the new value.

Use a WHERE clause in your query to update just one or some specified records.

```
UPDATE myTable SET myField = 'newValue' WHERE tableId = 'yourId';
```

Comment: I do include a `WHERE` clause in my `updateProject`-function, no?

Comment: If you have it, I think you have some errors while you are running your query. Can you check if is there any error ?